# removing blank lines python

Tags: python

I am pulling information from a web site (in this case ip/location etc) using python 3

```
import urllib.request

data = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_my_ip')
for search in data:
    if b'align="center">' in search:
        print(next(data).decode().rstrip())
data.close()
```

How can I remove blank lines / put information into tuples / save as variables etc. I want to be able to start using the data gathered.

Comment: Have you considered using the python API instead? `http://www.maxmind.com/app/python`

Comment: @jordanm haha, ok so I hadn't seen that... I'll definitely have a look. As a general question though the post still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @jordanm, the best option is to use the [GeoIP Python API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/python)  for this.

But to answer your question - your code should probably look more like this:

```
import urllib.request, pprint

data = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_my_ip')

fields = []
for line in data:
    if b'class=output' in line:
        fields.append(next(data).decode('iso-8859-1').strip())
data.close()
```

Note that I have changed the test string, and blank lines have been included. This is to ensure that the fields can be easily identified by index.

To access the field values, you can do:

```
address = fields[0]
isp = fields[8]
domain = fields[-1]
```

If you want to remove specific fields:

```
del fields[3], fields[4], fields[6]
```

Comment: Thank you... I presume (reading dive into python at the moment) that I can then use del to delete empty array entries? One real question though, why do you use 'iso-8859-1'? not just decode()

Comment: @user969617. What do you want to do with the field values? If you remove the empty fields, you won't know which field is which. On the question of [`decode`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode): the `encoding` argument defaults to "utf-8", but the correct encoding for the webpage is "iso-8859-1".

Comment: There is no real need for me to remove the empty fields. I just felt it would be cleaner, as I could then refer to them as 1, 2, 3, 4 ...etc instead of 1, 2, 3, 5, 7,... and an excuse to try and use python a bit. The reason for all of this is because I have no idea how to use google locate with python. One day I will hopefully be able to look back and laugh at the humble beginnings.

Comment: @user969617. But you _want_ the blank fields included so that they can be accessed by index! You can't know for certain which fields will be missing, so you need them _all_ in order to pull the right value out of the list.

Comment: Thank you... All I had meant was that fields 3 4 and 6 are blank.

Comment: @user969617. It would make more sense to say: remove the unwanted fields (like the US-specific ones). Anyway, I have corrected my answer to hopefully give you what you want. Good luck with learning python!

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing html scaping / parsing etc, use a library like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

It sure beats manually handling scraping.